# Entity Framework doesn't like 0..1 to * relationships

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a database framework where I have two tables. The first table has a single column that is an identity and primary key. The second table contains two columns. One is a varchar primary key and the other is a nullable foreign key to the first table.

When adding the tables to the model I get the following validation error:

**Condition cannot be specified for Column member 'DetailsControlSetId' because it is marked with a 'Computed' or 'Identity' StoreGeneratedPattern.**

where 'DetailsControlSetId' is the second foreign key reference in the second table.

Steps to reproduce:

1) Create a new .Net 3.5 Client Profile project with Visual Studio 2010 RC.
2) Run scripts below against test database (empty database will do).
3) Create EDMX model, targeting the database created, but opt to not import any tables.
4) Update Model from Database selecting the two tables in the database (DetailsControlSet and Application).
5) Validate the EDMX model.

Table Creation Scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DetailsControlSet](
    [DetailsControlSetId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DetailsControlSet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [DetailsControlSetId] ASC
    )
)

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application](
    [ApplicationName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DetailsControlSetId] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ApplicationName] ASC
    )
)

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Application]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Application_DetailsControlSet] FOREIGN KEY([DetailsControlSetId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DetailsControlSet] ([DetailsControlSetId])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Application] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Application_DetailsControlSet]
GO
```

Comment: Is the foreign key column actually store-generated or is the designer importing the model incorrectly? Also, which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410590/what-is-the-proper-way-to-create-a-recursive-entity-in-the-entity-framework @Orion, please answer the question I asked on your original question rather than reposting the same thing.

Comment: Hmmm, duplicate of this, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382135/recursive-entity-causing-all-sorts-of-problems

Comment: @Orion - If your previous questions on the same problem aren't getting answered, provide more information, and ask for a Bounty.

Comment: Just wait until you get to actually using the entities. I'm going back to therapy just for saying that.

Comment: This isn't the same question. This is a non-recursive pair of entities which isn't the same as my previous questions. Additionally my first question was the one with the most information which got neither comments nor answers.

Comment: @Rory: The foreign key column isn't store-generated, but the model seems to import certain tables and mark certain columns as store generated even when they're not (at least to my understanding).

Comment: @F.Aquino: I've actually used Linq-to-SQL and Linq-to-Entities since they first came out and I have created fairly robust solutions. This has just been the one that's problematic.

Comment: @Orion, both too little information and too much information are likely to cause a question to be overlooked. Here is how I would ask this question: 1) Reduce your metadata to a single table which you can add to Northwind or a blank DB. 2) Post that metadata along with the error message. You may not think these are duplicate issues, but *your questions read like duplicates*, even if the issues themselves are not.

Comment: @Craig: I had reduced it to a single table and the appropriate metadata for just that table so that it could be added to northwind on the other question (that got no responses). Unfortunately the edmx schemas are very verbose and even a single table can still be hundreds of lines.

Comment: You don't need to post the EDMX if you're just importing the one table with no customizations.

Comment: OK, I just spent 5 minutes creating a DB using your script and generating an EF model. Works fine. That said, your sample DB script doesn't match the error message you supply, so I'm not sure you've tried these steps.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: with which version of Visual Studio did you generate the model?

Comment: You didn't say which one you used, so I used 2010.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: First thanks for you assistance on this. I am using VS 2010 set to 3.5 as the framework and it gives me the problem on importing the table. I'll have to further investigate what's going on. But my question is, does the model import with a 0..1 to many relationship?

Comment: I think so, but I can't remember. I used the default settings, though, since you didn't say otherwise, so it would have been a .NET 4.0 project.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: Could you please post the XML for the entity model that was generated for those tables.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: It appears as if the logic for adding entities is different if you "Update Model from Database" versus adding them during the initial creation phase. The EDMX schema generated is different.

Comment: The above is also all using the 3.5 Client Profile

Comment: Um, yes, it is. This is documented. SSDL is regenerated from scratch when updating. CSDL attempts to preserve any changes you (may) have made. Don't keep us guessing by posting the same error message over and over, Orion. Make a **real** test case with step-by-step instructions -- the kind you'd want to get from your own testers -- and rewrite your question to have a minimal test case with simple steps that *reproduces for you.* You cannot expect people here to put more effort into fixing your problem than you put into describing it.

Comment: I am and was aware that SSDL regenerates and CSDL attempts to preserve changes. My point is that if you add the same tables to an empty model you will get a different result than if you add them during the initial creation. I'm not sure what changes it would be trying to preserve against an empty model, but that's what it does. Without knowing what exactly was the issue I was left only with test cases that would prove far too large to fit here. They reproduced for me, but wouldn't work here. The more information I seemed to take away from my original question the more responses I got.

Comment: I had changed the question to include the steps to reproduce after you initial request. See above.

Comment: Now that you've posted actual, reproduceable steps, I can help you with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** Now that you've (finally!) posted steps to reproduce this, I can make the error happen on my machine. And diffing the EDMX of the "import everything at first" vs. the "import tables later" models makes the problem obvious. The "working" model has this line:

```
<Property Name="DetailsControlSetId" Type="int" />
```

The "error" model has this line:

```
<Property Name="DetailsControlSetId" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
```

That's the only substantive difference between the two models.

So to fix this:

1. Right click EDMX in Solution Explorer.
2. Open with XML editor.
3. Delete `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"`
4. Note that the error immediately goes away.

Having this test case, I was able to do some research. It turns out [this is a known bug in VS 2010 beta and was fixed a few days ago](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533811/entity-framework-designer-generates-incorrect-storegeneratedpattern-values-for-join-table).

Comment: I knew about the differences in the model and how to fix it manually. I was looking for a root cause. Thank you for the research in finding out that this was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This article might help, was posted at `ADO.NET` `official` team blog

- [**Foreign Key Relationships in the
  Entity Framework**](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/11/06/foreign-key-relationships-in-the-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately this is all basic information I already know. I'm not looking for how to setup a basic entity, but rather how to setup this 0..1 to * relationship.

Comment: Your sample DB script already works correctly for me. I applied it to an empty DB and generated an EF model. No errors.